# What is causing cfn-signal with waithandle.url to get 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami

Good day.

My cloudformation stack keeps getting rolled back due to the error for the WaitCondition.

The EC2 instance has Userdata which calls custom bootstrap.sh that uses cfn-signal with the waithandle.url (replaced sensitive info with "masked"):

```
cfn-signal --success true --http-proxy http://proxyAbc:123 --https-proxy http://proxyAbc:123  --region ap-southeast-2 https://cloudformation-waitcondition-ap-southeast-2.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aap-southeast-2%3A747462550105%3Astack/asg-masked-20200508162554-0b080289adf738030/35459000-90f5-11ea-a7af-0a0ad6464e74/WaitHandle?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200508T062906Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86399&X-Amz-Credential=masked&X-Amz-Signature=masked
```

However it is encountering this error now:

```
Error signaling CloudFormation: [Errno 403] HTTP Error 403 : AccessDeniedAccess DeniedXYZ...123
```

There has been no code change **except for using a new Centos 7 AMI**.

Has anyone encountered this error and managed to resolve it?

**Edit:**
The userdata has this in the CloudFormation template (which has single-quote surrounding it), where the WAITHANDLE environment variable is used in the cfn-signal command above (the https://cloudformation-waitcondition-ap-southeast-2....):

```
BASH_SCRIPT[8]=\"export WAITHANDLE='", {"Ref": "WaitHandle"}, "'\"\n
```

Comment: The waithandle url is complex. Sometimes having it in quotes, helps to solve some strange issues when called in user data.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the comment, but yes it is surrounded in single quotes.

Answer (score 4):

The issue turned out to be due to proxy issue.
The proxy being used works before (for years) but now has been broken.
This is probably not a general answer as the 403 seems to be to broad, though pay attention to the part where it says AccessDenied (without 'Request has Expired') in any case just answering this in case anyone else encounters it.

For example:

**Pre-signed URL expired:**

```
Error signaling CloudFormation: [Errno 403] HTTP Error 403 : 
AccessDeniedRequest has expired863992020-05-15T05:17:56Z2020-05-18T20:41:19Z[somehashvalue]
```

**Proxy issue:**

```
Error signaling CloudFormation: [Errno 403] HTTP Error 403 : AccessDeniedAccess Denied[somehashvalue]
```